# Unexpected auto indentation by 8 spaces with AucTeX

Tags: indentation, auctex, doom

It's currently hitting the standard list-like environments and comments but I can't quite figure when exactly it happens, as it looks non-deterministic: sometimes in a big document I actually get a reasonable 2-space indentation inside those environments. Currently, this is what I get when I start a new document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
        \item asdasdsadsad     asdasdsadsad     asdasdsadsad     asdasdsadsad
        asdsa asdasd asadasdsadas asdasdsaasdasdsadsad     asdasdsadsad     asd
        asd asd asdasdsad
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
        \item asdsdas   asdsdas   asdsdas   asdsdas   asdsdas   asdsdas   asd
        asd asdasdsa
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

So, when I insert an environment using `yas-insert-snippet`. I enter the name of the environment, hit Tab,  and I start an `\item`, write a text till the end of line as set by `fill-column`  and the text auto-wraps (as it should), but it also auto-indents with **8 spaces**. This makes it completely unusable on narrow screens!

I tried explicitly calling `LaTeX-fill-environment`, and it does something similarly bad but a little different, so for the  `enumerate` from the example above is does:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item asdasdsadsad asdasdsadsad asdasdsadsad asdasdsadsad asdsa asdasd
        asadasdsadas asdasdsaasdasdsadsad asdasdsadsad asd asd asd asdasdsad
\end{enumerate}
```

So, still 8 spaces but starting from the second line of an item.

I checked related variables that I know of (most likely, there are others), they're pretty much the reasonable defaults that make perfect sense:

- `LaTeX-item-indent` value is `0`
- `LaTeX-indent-level`  value is `2`

I'm using Doom Emacs and my Doom config: https://github.com/ulysses4ever/dotfiles/tree/main/doom.d It's very minimally tuned from the default one. I use Emacs 29.0.92 (pgtk edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Doom Emacs, but I think what you describe is more a feature of Doom Emacs and not AUCTeX.  IIUC, you have to adjust the variable [`+latex-indent-item-continuation-offset`](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/7a7503045850ea83f205de6e71e6d886187f4a22/modules/lang/latex/config.el#L3):

```el
(defconst +latex-indent-item-continuation-offset 'align
  "Level to indent continuation of enumeration-type environments.

I.e., this affects \\item, \\enumerate, and \\description.

Set this to `align' for:

  \\item lines aligned
         like this.

Set to `auto' for continuation lines to be offset by `LaTeX-indent-line':

  \\item lines aligned
    like this, assuming `LaTeX-indent-line' == 2

Any other fixed integer will be added to `LaTeX-item-indent' and the current
indentation level.

Set this to `nil' to disable all this behavior.

You'll need to adjust `LaTeX-item-indent' to control indentation of \\item
itself.")
```

Comment: This looks to be it, thank you so much!!!